# Inverse of a matrix over a finite field from inverse over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: matrices, finite-fields, inverse

Suppose we have an invertible matrix (Over $F$) $A$ with entries over $F$, say, where $F$ is any field of characteristic $k \neq 0$. The first question is:

> Is it $A$ always invertible over $\mathbb{Q}$? If so...

If the inverse of $A$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $A^{-1}_{\mathbb{Q}}$, and $A^{-1}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is in the form $A^{-1}_{\mathbb{Q}} =  (a_{ij})$,

> Is it true that $A_{F}^{-1} = (a_{ij} \ \  mod \ k) $?

Example as it seems what I am asking is unclear:
Let $$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 \\ 
2 & 2 & 0\\ 
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, $$ with entries over $F_5$, the finite field of characteristic $5$. Now this matrix is invertible over $F_{5}$ and $$A_{F_5}^{-1}= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 3 & 4\\ 
3 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}.$$ And if we consider the same matrix but we inverse it over $\mathbb{Q}$, we get $$A_{\mathbb{Q}}^{-1}= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & \frac{1}{2} & -1 \\ 
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & -\frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}. $$

But considering $\frac{1}{2}_{F_5}=(2)^{-1}_{F_5}=3$ and $-1=4$, it is clear that the result holds, i.e. $$A_{F_5}^{-1} = A_{\mathbb{Q}}^{-1} \  mod \ 5 . $$

Is this always true for invertible matrices over the finite field?

Comment: It might happen that $a_{ij}=\frac1{k}$ ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That shouldn't happen unless $A$ is singular, right? I will edit the question so that $A$ is always invertible.

Comment: But what is the inverse of $A$ over $\Bbb Q$ if one of the entries of $A$ is $\in \Bbb F_4\setminus \Bbb F_2$?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you mean...

Comment: I guess you mean $A \in \mathbb{Z}^{n \times n}$, $A_p \equiv A \bmod p$ such that $A_p$  is inversible in $\mathbb{F}_p^{n \times n}$. If $A$ is not inversible then $\det(A) = 0 \implies \det(A_p) \equiv 0\bmod p$  so that $A_p$ is not inversible.

Comment: The question is not clear (and some people start already guessing).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have added an example...

Comment: Your question still doesn't mean what you want. See my answer, you need to start from a matrix with integer entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix#Definition).

$M_n(R)$ is the ring of $n \times n$ matrices with coefficients in a commutative ring $R$.

If $A \in M_n(\mathbb{Z})$ and $A_p \in M_n(\mathbb{F}_p),\ A_p \equiv A \bmod p$ then 
$$A\ \text{adj}(A) = \det(A) I \qquad  \text{in } M_n(\mathbb{Z})$$
Whose reduction $\bmod p$ of each term is
$$A_p\ \text{adj}(A_p) = \det(A_p) I \qquad  \text{in } M_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$$

If $\det(A_p) \not\equiv 0 \bmod p$ then $\det(A) \ne 0$ and
$$A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det(A)}\text{adj}(A)\qquad \text{in } M_n(\mathbb{Q})$$
whose reduction $\bmod p$ of each term is
$$  \qquad A_p^{-1} =\frac{1}{\det(A_p)}\text{adj}(A_p) \qquad \text{in } M_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$$

Comment: So... Are you assuming $p$ is a prime number? If so this means "yes" to my question when k="prime number", right?

Comment: @D1X $p$ is prime

Comment: @D1X $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ is a finite field of characteristic $p$. However what I wrote works in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, if $\det(A_n) \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^\times$

Comment: Excuse me but I don't understand the answer given. I don't get if it is a 'yes' or 'no'. First of all, What does $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^\times$ mean? As far as I know the result should be true if the field's cardinal is a prime number $p$, but not if the cardinal is a power of $p$...

Comment: @D1X  Inverting a matrix $A$ is the same as finding a matrix $B$ and a non-zero constant $c$ such that $AB = c I$. With $B = adj(A)$ then $B$ is an integer matrix if $A$ is an integer matrix, so we can reduce $A,B,AB,c = \det(A)$ modulo $n$ and obtain what I wrote.

Comment: @D1X Also I told you to look at the adjugate matrix wikipedia's article :  an integer matrix $A$ is invertible modulo $n$ iff $\det(A)$ is invertible modulo $n$ (which is what $\det(A_n) \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^\times$ means)